# AppEngine Security Constraint URL pattern

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Currently, I have this security constraint for my GAE app.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I want to have the same security constraint on all URL with the word admin e.g. /user/admin, /m/admin/index.jsp.

What url-pattern will work?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use multiple `<url-pattern>` in your `<security-constraint>`, this will make it more obvious when browsing `web.xml` what are the constraints of each root URLs:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/m/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```